# How to prevent launcher activity to appear in android multitask section?

Tags: android

I want to create an activity which perform some background operation and kill itself.

I don't want to show this activity in Android multitask section.

Please let me know how to prevent my launcher activity to appear in android multitask section?

Thank you,

Bikash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add his to the Activity's tag in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

Comment: Amazing how long it took for me to find this. Thanks for sharing.